# Как генерировать Json на C#, если структура динамическая, не прописывая все возможные варианты?

Tags: c#, json

Я генерирую json с помощью библиотеки `Newtonsoft.Json;`
Ответ должен быть типа `{Command:"CommandName", Data:{"Param1":1,"Param2":2}}`
Всегда будет структура Command и Data, но содержимое разное. Но и структура Data тоже разная.
Как организовать структуру, что б если Command="команда 1", то генерировалось по одному сценарию, а если другая- то по-другому?

Например:

```
{Command:"FilesList", Data:{"Files":["file1","file2","file3","file4"]}}
{Command:"UserInfo", Data:{"UserId":1, "UserName": "Roman" ....}}
```

Тоесть- я создам соответствующие классы FilesList,UserInfo, а вот как передать "неопределённый" класс? или делать перегрузки метода?
Может как-то описать базовый класс, где будет Command и Data и как-то в Data засовывать соответвтвующие классы и потом генерировать json?
Так я создаю json.

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DataInfo, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: А для чего все это, можно поподробней, а то попахивает костылем?

Answer (score 4):

Можно создать Json из анонимного типа:

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    ...

    public string Serialize(string command, object data) =>
        JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            Command = command,
            Data = data,
        }).ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class CommandContainer<TData>
    where TData: class
{
    public string Command { get; set; } 
    public TData Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Для JSON сойдет и такой тип, для XML + DataContract нужно будет еще задекорировать [KnownTypeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)